# Error:Failed to resolve: org.mockito:mockito-core

Tags: android, gradle, mockito

When I tried to upgrade **mockito** for my Android project, from *2.8.47* to *2.13.3*, I got an error:

```
Error:Failed to resolve: org.mockito:mockito-core:2.13.3
```

All my gradle configurations are correct, worked perfectly with *2.8.47* (below I just replace the mockito version with the latest one).

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

ext {
    mockitoVersion = "2.13.3"
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation "org.mockito:mockito-core:${mockitoVersion}"
}
```

And when doing gradle sync, you can see at the bottom of Android Studio, there are some logs:

```
Gradle: Download https://maven.google.com/org/mockito/mockito-core/2.13.3/mockito-core-2.13.3.pom
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually **mockito** is not hosted on *maven.google.com*.

The issue is due to two facts:

- From **mockito** project repository, you can find [a list of released versions](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/releases), including *v2.13.3*
- The library artifact is distributed at [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core), and you'll see from there, not all released versions are available for downloading, for instance, *2.13.0* is listed there but not *2.13.3*

**Solution**:

Change the dependency version to *2.13.0* instead of *2.13.3*, then it works fine.

**Lessons Learnt**:

Always check with **mvnrepository**, don't trust the release page of the project.

Comment: I also faced the problem while trying to sync it via the office network, may be they have blocked the download the files from not trusted urls. Just I connected the  internet with my hotspot. This problem got resolve.